# Application Deployment

Tags: deployment, installation, windows-installer

I deployed an application using [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656819.aspx) and it worked very good. However, there are 2 missing things that I been trying to find but can't:

1) How do I include resource files in the installation? I have a folder with files that have some user data, and those need to be there after the installation so the application can run, this is an oversimplified example I'm working on **(I need to include NecessaryFile1.xml, NecessaryFile2.xml and NecessaryFile3.xml and the folder they're in)**:

[alt text http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/7782/resources.png](http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/7782/resources.png)

2) How can I put the application in the start -> programs menu? It doesn't seem to do that either. It just puts it in the C:\Program Files\My Company Name\ApplicationName\ directory.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Right-click in the File System tab, click "Add Special Folder" and select "User's Start Menu".

Comment: Oops ... then you need to create a shortcut in the start menu folder (instead of actually adding the project output).

Comment: what should the shortcut point at? I tried pointing at the output and it didn't work. And that's pretty much everything I can point it at (beside the data files I needed to add).

Comment: Actually, I think it did work, it created an icon that looks like a paper, but I didn't realize I could change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Setup project in Visual Studio.  In the "File System" tab, locate "Application Folder".  Right-click and then click Add | Folder.  Name the new folder "Data".  Right-click on the new "Data" folder and click Add File, then add the needed XML files.  Repeat for as many different folders and/or files as required by your application.

When you compile and run your setup project, the "Data" folder and its contents will be deployed along with the application.

Comment: Beautiful! It worked! Thanks man. BTW, do you happen to know the answer for my second problem with this? 2) How can I put the application in the start -> programs menu? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Click on each XML file in the Solution Explorer and then in the Properties window below (see your screenshot) you click and change "Build Action" to "Copy" and "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy If Newer". That does the trick for me, at least with ClickOnce...

Comment: I tried that too, and it does copy it into the Debug or Release folders, but not when I do the install process. Thanks for the suggestion!